# Better explanation of numbers visible in UI/profile

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-display

Although I'm a regular user of SE sites, I haven't yet come across a clear page explaining how the various numbers in the profile, UI, or android app, work and what they mean. For example, on superuser s/e my profile shows with 69/1/7 next to it; on stack overflow it's 79/5. It isn't clear to me if there is any sort of "global rep", or how these numbers are calculated from other numbers shown next to individual questions and comments on those sites. On the app there's also a box on the top-right UI, with a zero in it; touching it drops down a list of questions and comments but its not clear to me what the zero represents. So I'm asking here for a helping hand to the help page I might have missed:)

The only "help" I can find on Meta SE says to hover over these to read more, an action that assume a mouse-based GUI (can't hover on a touchscreen).

At the least maybe a "?" Icon next to these or on help-> profile to explain what I'm looking at?

Any chance of a helping hand to understand better what I'm looking at and relate it back to my actual activity on questions? And perhaps improved findability of help on these?

Comment: Some screenshots would help explain your question.

Comment: Try hovering over the numbers.

Comment: @Oded he does mention in the question this part: *The only "help" I can find on Meta SE says to hover over these to read more, an action that assume a mouse-based GUI (can't hover on a touchscreen)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the mobile theme is indeed minimalistic, but still, I think those numbers are pretty self explaining themselves.

Here is the screenshot of your 69/1/7 on Super User that you mentioned:

> [image]

As you see, the most important detail is well explained with the word "REPUTATION" right next to the number. It can't be more obvious than that.

So this leaves us with the "1" and "7" numbers, that indeed you can't hover on a mobile device to get their meaning. Still, the silver and bronze colors around the numbers, plus the medal shape next to them should be enough to understand that these are badge counts: how many bronze badges and silver badges you have on the site.

I agree that in mobile theme, it will be a good idea if tapping the numbers will show a small popup with the title, but not adding any extra elements to the page.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. As it happens (and for your awareness) the colours and shapes  weren't enough to understand:  lacking info, my best guess was that they were some kind of count of questions/comments/positive feedbacks on the site. It wasn't obvious really how they should be interpreted, and its helpful to now know. Any hints on the big boxed number in the top right when using the app?

Comment: @Stilez cheers, the numbers in the app are the new inbox notifications (right most) and reputation change next to it. (not working in android app, so I guess you have iOS app?)

Comment: As often, 'self explanatory' assumes in-world knowledge. My first thought is, shouldn't this have been a bit more clear from Help or faq? I looked but, while there was an explanation of the rep system, there wasnt anything about "what are the other numbers on people's profile". That would help, if this is a suitable place for that kind of feedback.

Comment: Android but "something related to recent posts or notifications" makes sense as the dropdown on it is a list of posts/comments. Thanks again

Comment: Well, I'm considering to start a feature request asking to have the badge counts be a link to the user's badges list, which will make it obvious what those numbers are when clicking/tapping them. As for other numbers, well, sometimes experience is the best tutor. :)